# super on extended/included methods ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way I can `super` a method which is added from extending a module? I am using elasticsearch and need to include the methods

```
class Someclass
  include Elasticsearch::Model

  class << self
    alias_method :importing, :import
  end
  def self.import(options = {})
    transform = lambda do |a|
        {index: {_id: "#{a.resource_id},#{a.ayah_key}", _parent: a.ayah_key, data: a.__elasticsearch__.as_indexed_json}} 
    end
    options = {transform: transform}.merge(options)
    self.importing options 
  end

end
```

The import method from elasticsearch:

```
   def import(options={}, &block)
      errors       = []
      refresh      = options.delete(:refresh)   || false
      target_index = options.delete(:index)     || index_name
      target_type  = options.delete(:type)      || document_type
      transform    = options.delete(:transform) || __transform
      return_value = options.delete(:return)    || 'count'

      unless transform.respond_to?(:call)
        raise ArgumentError,
              "Pass an object responding to `call` as the :transform option, #{transform.class} given"
      end

      if options.delete(:force)
        self.create_index! force: true, index: target_index
      end

      __find_in_batches(options) do |batch|
        response = client.bulk \
                     index:   target_index,
                     type:    target_type,
                     body:    __batch_to_bulk(batch, transform)

        yield response if block_given?

        errors +=  response['items'].select { |k, v| k.values.first['error'] }
      end

      self.refresh_index! if refresh

      case return_value
        when 'errors'
          errors
        else
          errors.size
      end
    end
```

When I do `self.import`, I get stack level too deep error, and when i use `super` I get no superclass method to super

**Update**
Made it work by added `alias_method` See above.

Comment: Provide the implementation of `import` to see why's going into a loop.

Comment: https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails/.rubygem/elasticsearch-model/.def/Elasticsearch/Model/Importing/ClassMethods/$methods/import

Comment: Don't do this. Copy the relevant code and post it here instead of providing an external link where your source may lie.

Answer (score 1):

When using `import options` like this:

```
def import options
  # code...
  import options 
end
```

You're making a recursive call to the `import` method defined in `Someclass`, thus getting an infinite loop.

If you're including the module, then just do this:

```
class Someclass
  include Elasticsearch::Model::ClassMethods

  def import (options = {})
    transform = lambda do |a|
        {index: {_id: "#{a.resource_id},#{a.ayah_key}", _parent: a.ayah_key, data: a.__elasticsearch__.as_indexed_json}} 
    end
    options = {transform: transform}.merge(options)
    #calling import method from the module
    super options
  end
end
```

Comment: I get error: `NoMethodError: super: no superclass method 'import' for #<Class:0x007f958aadbd90>`

Comment: @MohamedElMahallawy uh, you were looking for `Elasticsearch::Model::ClassMethods` module, not `Elasticsearch::Model`

Comment: Are you importing the file at the beginning using `require`, right?

Comment: It's a gem. It's working perfectly fine if I just do `Theclass.import`

Comment: What happens if i use alias_method?

Comment: Any ideas what to do?

Comment: This should work as expected. It's very strange why you cannot include the module. Are you sure the gem is right installed in your project and you can access to all the modules there? If not, you may try using `require`.

Comment: I can access the gem's functions and it's all working perfectly fine

Comment: I'm wondering if you can really access to all the modules in the gem. Also, the error you stated at the beginning means that you don't have a method called `import` in whatever class you're testing. Could you provide your exact code where this error raises?

Comment: `Someclass.included_modules` returns all the modules of elastic search and if i do `.methods` returns all the methods used in ES.

Comment: Just `import` is recursive and returns `stack too deep`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that extend adds class methods to Someclass, so you may need to do:

```
class Someclass
  extend SomeModuleWithImportMethod

  def self.import
    ...
    super
  end

end
```